# Prove that $\dim(V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)=1$ or $\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)=3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_1,V_2,V_3$ be 2-dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$ with $\dim(V_i\cap V_j)=1$ for $i\ne j$. Prove that either $\dim(V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)=1$ or $\dim (V_1+V_2+V_3)=3$.

Originally I thought I can apply some kind of inclusion-exclusion principle $$\dim(V_1+V_2+V_3)=\dim V_1+\dim V_2+\dim V_3-\sum_{i\ne j} \dim(V_i\cap V_j)+\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)$$

But then I realized that this formula is not true when the $V_i$ are distinct lines in $\mathbb R^2$. So how do I prove what is required then?

Comment: **Hint**: $\dim(V_1 \cap V_2) = 1$, what does this tell you about the possible values of $\dim(V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)$ can only be $0$ or $1$ since $\dim (V_1\cap V_2)=1$. The question amounts to prove

> $$\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)=0\Longrightarrow \dim (V_1+ V_2+ V_3)=3$$

So assume that $\dim (V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3)=0$. Since $\dim(V_i\cap V_j)=1$ iff $i\neq j$, we derive

$$V_1=(V_1\cap V_2)\oplus(V_1\cap V_3)$$
and similarly for $V_2$ and $V_3$.

Therefore $$V_1+V_2+V_3=(V_1\cap V_2)+(V_1\cap V_3)+(V_2\cap V_3)$$
which implies that

> $$\dim (V_1+ V_2+ V_3)\leq 3.$$

---

But we also have

> $$\dim (V_1+ V_2+ V_3)\geq 3$$

since $V_2\not \subseteq V_1$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the last two inequalities, even though you indicated what they follow from. I would think one needs some kind of inclusion-exclusion formula to deduce them.

Comment: @user538518 No inclusion-exclusion. For the first, $V_1+V_2+V_3$ is a sum of three subspaces of dimension $1$, therefore its dimension is at most $3$. For the last one, $V_2$ has dimension $2$ and $V_1$ is not contained in $V_2$ so the sum has dimension at least one more than $V_2$

Comment: Why do we need that the sum is direct? The equalities like $V_1=(V_1\cap V_2)+(V_1\cap V_3)$ hold without assumptions on the triple intersection, and don't they imply $V_1+V_2+V_3=\sum V_i\cap V_j$?

Comment: @user538518 No, the equality that you mention doesn't hold without the triple intersection assumption. If the triple intersection is not trivial, then $(V_1\cap V_2)+(V_1\cap V_3)=(V_1\cap V_2)$ has dimension $1$ and certainly cannot be equal to $V_1$.

Comment: Why is $(V_1\cap V_2)+(V_1\cap V_3)=V_1\cap V_2$ if the triple intersection is not trivial? I thought you used that the triple intersection is trivial to conclude that $(V_1\cap V_2)\cap(V_1\cap V_3)$ is trivial, which along with  $V_1=(V_1\cap V_2)+(V_1\cap V_3)$  gives $V_1=(V_1\cap V_2)\oplus (V_1\cap V_3)$.

Comment: Because of the dimensions: if the triple intersection is not trivial then it has dimension $1$ and therefore is equal to $V_i\cap V_j$ for any $i\neq j$.

Comment: I see. Then how do you derive that the trivial triple intersection implies $V_1=(V_1\cap V_2)+(V_1\cap V_3)$?

Comment: @user538518 You should be able to work it out, at this point it is really elementary.

Comment: Is it because $V_1\cap V_2$ and $V_1\cap V_3$ are two 1-dimensional subspaces of the 2-dimensional space $V_1$ that do not coincide because the triple intersection is trivial? That sounds not rigorous enough to me. I need to prove that any vector in $V_1$ is the sum of a vector in $V_1\cap V_2$ and a vector in $V_1\cap V_3$, but the above thoughts do not make it explicit how to do this.

Comment: @user538518 That's absolutely true and rigorous. There doesn't need to be an explicit way to decompose a given vector. You were ok with the argument $V_2\not\subseteq V_1\implies \dim(V_2+V_1)>\dim(V_1)$, it's the same argument here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since the $V_j$'s are all 2 dimensional and you have $\dim(V_1 \cap V_2)=1,$ and $V_1 \cap V_2\cap V_3$ is a subspace of $V_1 \cap V_2$, then it must be $V_1 \cap V_2\cap V_3$ has dimension $1$, or $V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3 =0$, this last case tells us $$(V_1 \cap V_2
)+V_3=(V_1 \cap V_2) \oplus V_3$$